# Method definitions for methods contained in System.Xml.XMLReader

Tags: c#, methods, definition, system.xml

I haven't been able to find a reference that defines what these methods are made up of.

I kind of get what these methods do and what arguments they take, but I'm hoping to find out *how* they work.

I'd like to find something that would give me a definition such as

```
void System.Xml.Xmlreader()
{
//class constructor function
}
```

for all or most of the methods in this class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method signatures are available on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader_methods.aspx

If you click on the method names, you'll see a definition, explanation, and usually some code examples.

Edit: Also, if you right click on the using directive and choose "Go to Definition" in Visual Studio, you can view the metadata for the class.